# Hamilton's letter to his son

Tags: reference-request, quaternions

I'm looking for a better reference on this letter [from Hamilton to his son](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Letters/BroomeBridge.html) where he wrote about his discovering on Quaternions.

I'd like to read, if it is possible, a scanned version of the letter.

Where can I find that letter?